# Ag Grid: Hide Value Column Header in Pivot Mode

Tags: ag-grid

I am trying to export Ag-Grid as an Excel in Pivot Mode:

[image]

But I don't want the Value Column Headers in Excel (sum(Gold), sum(Bronze) etc.)

Is it possible to remove that row entirely in Ag-Grid ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `skipColumnHeaders` set in the `defaultExcelExportParams`. Example here: https://plnkr.co/edit/doNiLJ9pT7anKBYa?open=main.js

```
defaultExcelExportParams: {
    skipColumnHeaders: true
  }
```